# brand new conda environment appearing to have lots of requirements

Tags: conda

I'm creating a a fresh conda environment for the purpose of starting with a clean environment without any dependencies. However when I run pip freeze > requirements.txt immediately after creating and activating it, it aleready contains over 300 packages. What do I need to do to fix this, ie. create a clean environment using my conda?

```
(base) conda create --name new_env1 python=3.11
(base) conda activate new_env1
(new_env1) pip freeze > requirements.txt (produces 300+ packages)
(new_env1) pip freeze -l > requirements.txt (same result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Running

```
python -m site
```

Reported (amongst others)

```
USER_BASE: $HOME/.local
```

Underneath, there was lib/python3.11 with TONS of files in it.
As a workaround (I can't say I'm aware of the consequences) I renamed it, re-created the conda environment and it appears to be clean.